# Right way of Exception handling when using Akka actors

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to do proper Exception handling in my Akka projects by using supervisors. Just wanted to be sure if this is the right way of approaching things.
I have 1 Actor system which creates 4 seperate actors.Lets say 1 of my actor is hitting a DB. Is supervision strategy the right way of handling things?

```
object ExceptionHandlingSupervisor extends App{
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ExceptionHandlingActorSystem")
  val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[SupervisorActor], "SupervisorActor")
  actor ! Start

  class SupervisorActor extends Actor {
    val dbActor = context.actorOf(Props[ChildActor],"ChildActor")
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case Start => dbActor ! HitDatabase("","")
    }

    override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(loggingEnabled = false){
      case ae:SQLException => println("Found an SQLException") //Add my logging logic here and error notification logic here
        Resume

      case _:Exception => println("Found an Exception")
        Restart

    }

  }

  class ChildActor extends Actor{
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case HitDatabase(user,pass) => dbFunction(user,pass)
    }
  }
}
```

Would the above code be the way to go for this approach or should I stick with conventional Try/Catch block:

```
class DbActor extends Actor{
        override def receive: Receive = {
          case HitDatabase(user,pass) => 
    try{
            dbFunction(user,pass)
          }
            catch {
              case ae:SQLException => println("Found an SQLException") //Add my logging logic here and error notification logic here
            }
```

Also I would really appreciate if you could tell,
why would the Supervisor approach be chosen over conventional exception handling under these circumstances?
Can we have specify some other error handling logic in the supervisorStrategy apart from just doing Resume or Restart ?

Comment: Does your dbFunction deals with Futures?

Comment: No it doesn't include any futures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless there are needs to handle Exceptions in a very granular fashion or differently within individual actors, I'd let the built-in supervisorStrategy handle the Exceptions and the corresponding actor restart/termination, etc.  It also has the benefit of better readability by having a central place for fault handling logic.

> Can we have specify some other error handling logic in the supervisorStrategy
>   apart from just doing Resume or Restart ?

There are other fault-handling actions such as [`Stop`, `Escalate`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fault-tolerance.html#creating-a-supervisor-strategy) in supervisorStrategy.  `Stop` terminates the child actor and `Escalate` escalates up the chain to the supervisor's parent.  Custom code can be added prior to returning a `Directive` within each `case`, as long as the [decider](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/SupervisorStrategy$.html#Decider=PartialFunction[Throwable,akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.Directive]) code block conforms to a `PartialFunction[Throwable, Directive]`.  For example:

```
override val supervisorStrategy =
  OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {
    case e: ArithmeticException =>
      myLogActor ! s"ERROR: $e from $sender; Resuming."
      Resume
    case _: Exception =>
      myLogActor ! s"ERROR: unknown exception from $sender; Escalating."
      Escalate
  }
```

As a side note, in case you must take the `try/catch` approach, consider using `Try` instead, as shown below:

```
Try(dbFunction(user, pass)) match {
  case Success(res)             => // do something with `res`
  case Failure(e: SQLException) => // log `e`, etc
  case Failure(e)               => // other exceptions ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer @Leo C . When I said any other actions, I meant some extra things apart from Resume, Restart, Stop or Escalate. Something like,
`case ae: ArithmeticException      => exceptionNotifier(ae)
 Resume`
Is it an antipattern? 
Also could you comment or redirect on how to handle some custom exceptions when using supervision model?

Comment: @Akhilanand, please see my expanded answer.

Comment: Although the suggestion regarding the Try approach really looks nice, too, why would I prefer it over the "classic" try/catch one? Doesn't this unnecessarily tie code more to a framework library than needed?

Comment: @Jonny Dee, `Try` doesn't require a separate framework.  It comes with Scala's standard library.  In short, it's more idiomatic to use `Try` as it is an ADT (algebraic data type), allowing chaining, composition, etc.  For more details, this [`blog post`](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-6-error-handling-with-try/) might be of interest.

Comment: @Leo C, thank you for your clatification the the link to the blog post.